# Getting correct $HOME directory in bash on google cloud

Tags: bash, centos, google-cloud-platform, centos6

My bash script has the following code and i  executed it on google cloud compute engine.

`mv $HOME/openvpn-2.4.0/ /etc/openvpn`

The problem here is that `$HOME` get expanded to `/root` instead of `/home/myusername`.

`echo $HOME` at command prompt gives `/home/myusername` as expected.

What am i doing wrong here ?

**Edit 1**

If i execute the bash script with sudo the `$HOME` variable gives `/root` , but when i execute the script without sudo the $HOME variable gives  `/home/myusername` as expected on google cloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used  $SUDO_USER to find the home directory

`HOME=$(getent passwd $SUDO_USER | cut -d: -f6)`

Answer (score 0):

When you run the bash script with sudo, it runs the script as root user, so the $HOME variable gives /root.

One option is to pass the $HOME environment variable as a command line option to your bash script. You can then access the value of this variable inside the bash script as $1.